# Need help with reversing data in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called location and it has data in it like:

texas_dallas
florida_miami

I am trying to create a SQL statement that will get rid of the _ and reverse the order so that I get:

dallas texas
miami florida

So far I have this statement which seems to get rid of the underscore and gives me only the entry before the _.

SELECT SUBSTR(location, 1 , INSTR(location, ‘_’)-1 ) AS output from general;

I am having some trouble figuring out the rest of what I need to do.

Comment: Is "texas_dallas florida_miami" in a single row, or is that data from two rows? "texas_dallas" in one row, "florida_miami" in the other?

Comment: They were two different rows.  Thanks again for the help as it is all good now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** Corrected order of output.

```
SQL> with general as (select 'texas_dallas' as location from dual
  2      union all select 'florida_miami' from dual)
  3  select substr(location, instr(location, '_') + 1)
  4      || ' ' || SUBSTR(location, 1 , INSTR(location, '_') -1) AS output
  5  from general;

OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dallas texas
miami florida
```

Comment: Nice.  But...  I see he didn't format his data in the question -- there is actually no ' ' between dallas and florida -- it's supposed to be separate records.

Comment: Thanks Shannon, but how do I get this to work on every state_city in the table?

Comment: @kuru kura na..: I think something might have been swollowed in your comments. Yes, I am assuming dallas and miami are in seperate records. I build up a view using `with` with two records, one for each city.

Comment: @Christopher: By dropping the `with` clause, and then using the appopriate table name for "general".

Comment: @Shannon -- oops -- thanks.  @Christopher -- the first 2 lines of @Shannon's answer you don't need.  The 5th line, replace 'general' with the name of your table.  yes?

Comment: @Shannon - I just ran the last three lines and I get the state and city without the _ but I still need them in reverse order.  Then I'll be all good.

Comment: Be sure to copy the current, edited, version of the answer. I had the order wrong in my first version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more to your expression. First concatenate a space, then use the SUBSTR function to extract the second word starting just after the underscore. Not supplying a length to SUBSTR takes the remainder of the text to the end.

```
select SUBSTR(location, 1 , INSTR(location, '_')-1 ) || ' ' || SUBSTR(location, INSTR(location, '_')+1 ) AS output 
from general ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also trying a REGEXP_REPLACE function:

```
select regexp_replace(location,'^(\S+)\_(\S+)$','\2 \1') from general;
```